# How to set the path of smallrye jwt key location?

Tags: quarkus, smallrye

Im my quarkus project, I want to set this propertie.

`smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location`

My application.propertie file looks like this.

`smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=privateKey.pem`
My key **privateKey.pem** located inside the root folder of my project. Everything works.

Now I want to copy the key into a subfolder jwt/. So I created a subfolder and copied the privateKey.pem into it.

projectFolder/jwt/privateKey.pem

My application.properties file is now like

`smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=jwt/privateKey.pem`

But now I got

```
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: jwt/privateKey.pem
```

How to correct specify the location?

Comment: Hi, are you resolved this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does prefixing with file:// help with anything？

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).